# How to change the volume of left channel using pulseaudio

Tags: 12.10, sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth, ffmpeg

I am recording the video using **logitech camera and bluetooth microphone**. Logitech can used for recording both audio and video.

When I turn on bluetooth microphone in the middle of recording, it is replacing the logitech audio channel due to this we are getting the bluetooth audio from the left channel.

But when I turn off the bluetooth then I get the logitech audio on left channel but the volume is very low and also getting the some noise.

I am using [PulseAudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio) and [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for recording purpose. So how can I increase / change the volume of left channel during runtime from the **command line**?

**Edit my ffmpeg command**

```
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -y -f v4l2 -s 544x288 -i /dev/video0 -vstats -vstats_file '/home/ubuntu/pra_app/videos/10-36-14/left-stats' -f pulse -name 'left_mic 0' -i alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_D81A0330-00-U0x46d0x823_1.analog-stereo  -f pulse -name 'right_mic 1' -i alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_4B709030-00-U0x46d0x823.analog-stereo  -f pulse -name 'default 0' -i default  -f mpegts -crf 20 -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -t 02:00:00 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 -map 3:0 /home/ubuntu/pra_app/videos/10-36-14/left.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you install `pavucontrol`. You can disable left and right volume alignment in pavucontrol, so that you can increase/decrease your left and right volume of your audio channel individually.

[image: PulseAudio Control]

Comment: Thanks, but I know this way. But I need to do this from command line and sorry for confusion. I have updated my question.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at http://blog.waan.name/pulseaudio-setting-volume-from-command-line/ for a scripting guide on how to that with PulseAudio

Comment: I know how to increase the volume, but I have to increase the volume at run time. I have edited my post.